# Find the three missing numbers down the diagonal of a grid

Tags: pattern

Which of the 5 answers fits the grid, and what is the pattern?

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ? | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | ? | 9 |
| 6 | 12 | ? |

- A. 13-21-18
- B. 10-18-19
- C. 12-20-19
- D. 11-22-15
- E. 19-19-19

Original [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gRft.png) found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/cv2ckh/im_stumped_by_this_missing_number_puzzle/)

> The answer is given as C, but no explanation is given as to why C is correct.

Comment: Do the dashes between the numbers just separate the numbers or denote negatives for the second two digits?

Comment: I believe they just separate the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I tried various techniques, but only this seemed to make any sense to me

> Each number should be written as the number of prime factors it has. This number is [1,2,3] in each row.

> eg -> 5 has only 1 prime factor '5'. So replace 5 with 1. 12 has 3 prime factors (2,2,3). So replace 12 with 3. And so on.

> Using this logic, we see that we need a number with 3 prime factors in first and second row and number with 1 prime factor in last row. Only 'c' satisfies our criteria